# Iris Wordpress theme slider not working

Tags: wordpress, slider, themes

I purchased the iris theme for my wordpress site. Everything works fine, but the slider will not show up on the home page no matter what. I have a static home page and added images at least 1060px wide like it wanted. I've read the docs but can't find any solution to my problem. If anyone has Iris experience and can lead me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! I forgot to choose the `Home Page` template under page attributes.